# Export files with AVAssetExportSession without changing their format (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession

In my app I download music files from the Music Library to the Documents folder.
I've tried many options, including looking on this site, but they all suggest using `AVAssetExportSession` and `.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a`. But I don't want to convert files to this format, I would like the files to be exported in the same format in which they are stored in the Music Library. How can I do it?

My code:

```
...
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: AVAsset(url: url), presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
...
```